# Kubernetes cluster role error: at least one verb must be specified

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following clusterrole

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["crontabs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

with the following error on create

```
jonathan@sc-test-cluster:~$ kubectl create clusterrole role.yml
error: at least one verb must be specified
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either create it from file using `-f` or by specifying the options using `clusterrole`, see also the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.6/#-em-clusterrole-em-), but not both. Try the following:

```
$ kubectl create -f role.yml
```